# FileBeat not pulling MySQL logs?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logging, indexing, filebeat

Filebeat seems to not be pulling logs files from /var/log/mysql/mysql.log into ElasticSearch? Does anybody have any suggestions as to why this might not work? Thanks!

This is my filebeat.yml file:

```
    filebeat.input:
    - input_type: log
      enabled: true
      paths:
        - /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
      registry: /var/lib/filebeat/registry
    output.elasticsearch:
      hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
```

This is my mysql.yml file:

```
    - module: mysql

      error:
        enabled: false
        var.paths: ["/var/log/mysql/error.log"]

      slowlog:
        enabled: true
        var.paths: ["/var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log"]
```

This is the filebeat setup -e output:

```
    2021-06-02T14:32:27.309-0700    INFO    instance/beat.go:665    Home path: [/usr/share/filebeat] Config path: [/etc/filebeat] Data path: [/var/lib/filebeat] Logs path: [/var/log/filebeat]
    2021-06-02T14:32:27.309-0700    INFO    instance/beat.go:673    Beat ID: 0dbda706-e0e2-492b-98c6-724fb0a766ba
    2021-06-02T14:32:27.310-0700    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:1014   Beat info   {"system_info": {"beat": {"path": {"config": "/etc/filebeat", "data": "/var/lib/filebeat", "home": "/usr/share/filebeat", "logs": "/var/log/filebeat"}, "type": "filebeat", "uuid": "0dbda706-e0e2-492b-98c6-724fb0a766ba"}}}
    2021-06-02T14:32:27.310-0700    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:1023   Build info  {"system_info": {"build": {"commit": "2d80f6e99f41b65a270d61706fa98d13cfbda18d", "libbeat": "7.13.1", "time": "2021-05-28T17:43:52.000Z", "version": "7.13.1"}}}
    2021-06-02T14:32:27.310-0700    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:1026   Go runtime info {"system_info": {"go": {"os":"linux","arch":"amd64","max_procs":2,"version":"go1.15.12"}}}
    2021-06-02T14:32:27.310-0700    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:1030   Host info   {"system_info": {"host": {"architecture":"x86_64","boot_time":"2021-06-02T14:13:07-07:00","containerized":false,"name":"ubuntu","ip":["127.0.0.1/8","::1/128","192.168.142.131/24","fe80::303e:be71:ed56:fb5b/64"],"kernel_version":"5.8.0-53-generic","mac":["00:0c:29:7f:c9:7a"],"os":{"type":"linux","family":"debian","platform":"ubuntu","name":"Ubuntu","version":"20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)","major":20,"minor":4,"patch":2,"codename":"focal"},"timezone":"PDT","timezone_offset_sec":-25200,"id":"5e0372b7878743d49d4e11021f4b2bbf"}}}
    2021-06-02T14:32:27.311-0700    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:1059   Process info    {"system_info": {"process": {"capabilities": {"inheritable":null,"permitted":["chown","dac_override","dac_read_search","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","linux_immutable","net_bind_service","net_broadcast","net_admin","net_raw","ipc_lock","ipc_owner","sys_module","sys_rawio","sys_chroot","sys_ptrace","sys_pacct","sys_admin","sys_boot","sys_nice","sys_resource","sys_time","sys_tty_config","mknod","lease","audit_write","audit_control","setfcap","mac_override","mac_admin","syslog","wake_alarm","block_suspend","audit_read","38","39"],"effective":["chown","dac_override","dac_read_search","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","linux_immutable","net_bind_service","net_broadcast","net_admin","net_raw","ipc_lock","ipc_owner","sys_module","sys_rawio","sys_chroot","sys_ptrace","sys_pacct","sys_admin","sys_boot","sys_nice","sys_resource","sys_time","sys_tty_config","mknod","lease","audit_write","audit_control","setfcap","mac_override","mac_admin","syslog","wake_alarm","block_suspend","audit_read","38","39"],"bounding":["chown","dac_override","dac_read_search","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","linux_immutable","net_bind_service","net_broadcast","net_admin","net_raw","ipc_lock","ipc_owner","sys_module","sys_rawio","sys_chroot","sys_ptrace","sys_pacct","sys_admin","sys_boot","sys_nice","sys_resource","sys_time","sys_tty_config","mknod","lease","audit_write","audit_control","setfcap","mac_override","mac_admin","syslog","wake_alarm","block_suspend","audit_read","38","39"],"ambient":null}, "cwd": "/etc/filebeat", "exe": "/usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat", "name": "filebeat", "pid": 2781, "ppid": 2780, "seccomp": {"mode":"disabled","no_new_privs":false}, "start_time": "2021-06-02T14:32:26.840-0700"}}}
    2021-06-02T14:32:27.311-0700    INFO    instance/beat.go:309    Setup Beat: filebeat; Version: 7.13.1
    2021-06-02T14:32:27.311-0700    INFO    [index-management]  idxmgmt/std.go:184  Set output.elasticsearch.index to 'filebeat-7.13.1' as ILM is enabled.
    2021-06-02T14:32:27.311-0700    INFO    eslegclient/connection.go:99    elasticsearch url: http://localhost:9200
    2021-06-02T14:32:27.312-0700    INFO    [publisher] pipeline/module.go:113  Beat name: ubuntu
    2021-06-02T14:32:27.312-0700    INFO    eslegclient/connection.go:99    elasticsearch url: http://localhost:9200
    2021-06-02T14:32:27.343-0700    INFO    [esclientleg]   eslegclient/connection.go:314   Attempting to connect to Elasticsearch version 7.13.1
    Overwriting ILM policy is disabled. Set `setup.ilm.overwrite: true` for enabling.

    2021-06-02T14:32:27.364-0700    INFO    [index-management]  idxmgmt/std.go:261  Auto ILM enable success.
    2021-06-02T14:32:27.369-0700    INFO    [index-management.ilm]  ilm/std.go:160  ILM policy filebeat exists already.
    2021-06-02T14:32:27.369-0700    INFO    [index-management]  idxmgmt/std.go:401  Set setup.template.name to '{filebeat-7.13.1 {now/d}-000001}' as ILM is enabled.
    2021-06-02T14:32:27.369-0700    INFO    [index-management]  idxmgmt/std.go:406  Set setup.template.pattern to 'filebeat-7.13.1-*' as ILM is enabled.
    2021-06-02T14:32:27.369-0700    INFO    [index-management]  idxmgmt/std.go:440  Set settings.index.lifecycle.rollover_alias in template to {filebeat-7.13.1 {now/d}-000001} as ILM is enabled.
    2021-06-02T14:32:27.369-0700    INFO    [index-management]  idxmgmt/std.go:444  Set settings.index.lifecycle.name in template to {filebeat {"policy":{"phases":{"hot":{"actions":{"rollover":{"max_age":"30d","max_size":"50gb"}}}}}}} as ILM is enabled.
    2021-06-02T14:32:27.379-0700    INFO    template/load.go:228    Existing template will be overwritten, as overwrite is enabled.
    2021-06-02T14:32:28.385-0700    INFO    template/load.go:131    Try loading template filebeat-7.13.1 to Elasticsearch
    2021-06-02T14:32:28.627-0700    INFO    template/load.go:123    template with name 'filebeat-7.13.1' loaded.
    2021-06-02T14:32:28.627-0700    INFO    [index-management]  idxmgmt/std.go:297  Loaded index template.
    2021-06-02T14:32:28.632-0700    INFO    [index-management.ilm]  ilm/std.go:121  Index Alias filebeat-7.13.1 exists already.
    Index setup finished.
    Loading dashboards (Kibana must be running and reachable)
    2021-06-02T14:32:28.632-0700    INFO    kibana/client.go:119    Kibana url: http://localhost:5601
    2021-06-02T14:32:28.632-0700    ERROR   instance/beat.go:989    Exiting: error connecting to Kibana: fail to get the Kibana version: HTTP GET request to http://localhost:5601/api/status fails: fail to execute the HTTP GET request: Get "http://localhost:5601/api/status": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5601: connect: connection refused. Response: .
    Exiting: error connecting to Kibana: fail to get the Kibana version: HTTP GET request to http://localhost:5601/api/status fails: fail to execute the HTTP GET request: Get "http://localhost:5601/api/status": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5601: connect: connection refused. Response: .
```

This is the listing of /var/log/mysql:

```
    error.log  error.log.1.gz  error.log.2.gz  error.log.3.gz  error.log.4.gz  error.log.5.gz  mysql.log  mysql-slow.log
```

This is the my.cnf mysql config file:

```
    [mysqld]
    general_log = 1
    general_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
    slow_query_log = 1
    slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
    long_query_time = 1
    log_queries_not_using_indexes = 1

    !includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
    !includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

Also, if you open /var/log/mysql/mysql.log, a bunch of recent queries are listed...

Comment: Have you noticed the kibana related error in the log?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out! My coworker said that you don’t need Kibana installed... I will install it anyways, that’s probably why it’s not working.

Comment: you don´t need kibana for fetching logs, but then disable the kibana setup in the beat config https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/setup-kibana-endpoint.html

Comment: Thanks! I ended up buying books on this technology so I can understand it better.